# Can't seem to use mono (from host) in docker

Tags: docker, mono, dockerfile

I've installed `mono` ([complete](http://www.mono-project.com/download/#download-lin)) under Ubuntu Server 16.04, and tested it with `mono --version`. Then, I've installed `docker`, to be able to run a simple .NET app in a container, but using the host OS and `mono` (avoiding the need for `mono` within the container, based on [this tutorial](https://github.com/ninjarobot/mono-in-docker)).

But, running the docker container throws an error:

> standard_init_linux.go:187: exec user process caused "no such file or
>   directory"

The `Dockerfile` looks like:

```
FROM scratch
ENV PATH /mnt/monobin:$PATH
ENV LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/mnt/monolib:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH
COPY . /app
WORKDIR /app
CMD ["mono", "/app/monotest.exe"]
```

Build works fine:

```
docker build -t monotest .
```

Mounting the host directories containing Mono, and running like this doesn't work:

```
docker run -v /usr/bin:/mnt/monobin -v /usr/lib/mono:/mnt/monolib --rm monotest
```

So, is it possible to have a bare-bone docker container (no OS image or Mono image), and utilize the host OS and its packages?

Comment: They mention mounting `/opt/mono` in command `docker run -v /opt/mono:/mnt/mono --rm external_mono mono --version` and you are mount `/usr/bin` why?

Comment: Their config seems CentOS based, which may have those directories. But there's no `/opt/mono` when I do the complete mono install on Ubuntu. The binaries are in `/usr/bin` and its libraries are in `/usr/lib/mono`.

Comment: Try with centos and first see if that one works for you? Then we know its a ubuntu specific issue and rest of the stuff works?